# React Native Navigator is not showing initial route

Tags: react-native

I have a NavigatorIOS component and another component called Yolo that I want to display underneath the Navigator.  Here is my code:

```
class Yolo extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue', marginTop: 64}}>
          <Text>OkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobeeOkechobee</Text>
          <Text>grits</Text>
          <Text>hall and oats</Text>
          <Text>Okechobee</Text>
          <Text>grits</Text>
          <Text>hall and oats</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

class NavYo extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS initialRoute={{component: Yolo, title: 'Oh yea'}} />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => NavYo);
```

The Navigator appears without a proble.  It is correctly titled Yolo.  The Yolo component, however, does not appear.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: style={{flex: 1}} for NavigatorIOS

Comment: Thanks, that makes the view appear but it also changes the color of the Navigator.  There must be a way to make the view show but also not change the Navigator color?

Comment: @Philipp7899 an answer with an example to your question will be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a style={{flex:1}} for the navigator

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the question was why 'Yolo' was not visible, and the answer to that question is in fact that the parents flex should be set for the children flex to function correctly (if not, the side effect is the aforementioned visibility issue)

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!